# Doubt about a passage on page 24 of the Evans Partial Differential Equations book

Tags: partial-differential-equations, lp-spaces

Let $\Phi$ the fundamental solution of $\Delta v=0$, *i.e.*
$$
\Phi(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}-\frac{1}{2\pi}\log|x|& \mbox{if}& n=2\\ \frac{1}{n(n-1)\alpha(n)}\frac{1}{|x|^n-2}& \mbox{if}& n\geq 3\\ \end{array} \right.
$$
here $\alpha(n)$ denote the volume of unite ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. In page 23 of Evans Partial Differential Equations book Theorem 1 ( Solving Poisson's equation ) we have for $f\in C_c^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and 
$$
u(x)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y)f(y)\mathrm{d}y=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(y)f(x-y)\mathrm{d}y
$$
the following conclusions:
$$
\begin{array}{crl}
 \mathrm{(i)} &  u        &\in C^2(\mathbb{R}^n)
\\
\mathrm{(ii)}&  -\Delta u &= f
\end{array}
$$
In step 2 of the proof of this theorem, we have the following inequality
$$
\left|\int_{B(0,\epsilon)} \Phi(y)\Delta_x f(x-y)\mathrm{d} y\right|
\leq 
C\cdot \|D^2f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}\int_{B(0,\epsilon)} |\Phi(y)|\mathrm{d} y
$$

> **Question.** How can I prove that 
>   $$
> \left|\int_{B(0,\epsilon)} \Phi(y)\Delta_x f(x-y)\mathrm{d} y\right|
> \leq 
> C\cdot \|D^2f\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}\int_{B(0,\epsilon)} |\Phi(y)|\mathrm{d} y\quad ?
> $$

**My attempt:** We have 
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{B(0,\epsilon)} \Phi(y)\Delta_x f(x-y)\mathrm{d} y\right|
\leq &
\int_{B(0,\epsilon)} |\Phi(y)\Delta_x f(x-y)|\mathrm{d} y
\\
&\leq 
\mathop{\mathrm{sup \;ess}}|\Delta_x f(x-y)|\int_{B(0,\epsilon)} |\Phi(y)|\mathrm{d} y
\end{align}
This seems to indicate that I have to prove that
$$
\mathop{\mathrm{sup \;ess}}|\Delta_x f(x-y)|
\leq 
\mathop{\mathrm{sup \;ess}}|D^2_x f(x-y)|_{\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)}
$$
where $|\;\cdot \;|_{\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)}$ is a matrix norm.

Comment: Apply Holder's inequality with $p=1$ and $q=\infty$.

Comment: @Neal This is not my doubt. Note that on the one hand we have the $\mathop{\mathrm{sup \;ess}}|\Delta_x f(x-y)|$ and on the other side of the inequality we have $\mathop{\mathrm{sup \;ess}}|D^2_x f(x-y)|_{\mathscr{L}(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^n)}$.

Comment: @EliasCosta :  See : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3594384/a-question-about-the-proof-of-theorem-1-section-2-2-1-of-the-evans-pde/3619062#3619062

Answer (score 4):

Evan's defines$$\vert D^2 f \vert  = \bigg (\sum_{i,j=1}^n (D_{ij}f)^2 \bigg)^{\frac 1 2} $$ and $$ \| D^2 f \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)} = \| \vert D^2 f \vert  \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)} = \mathrm{ess}\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \bigg (\sum_{i,j=1}^n (D_{ij}f)^2 \bigg)^{\frac 1 2}.$$ Then for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $D_{ij} f (x) \leqslant \vert D^2 f \vert \leqslant \| D^2 f \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}$. Thus, by triangle inequality $$\vert \Delta f \vert \leqslant \sum_{i=1}^n \vert D_{ii}f \vert \leqslant n \| D^2 f \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}.$$

Comment: Why the inequality $ \vert D^2 f \vert \leqslant \| D^2 f \|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)}$ is always true? It holds only for almost everywhere? Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: $f$ is $C^2$, so everywhere and almost everywhere are the same

Comment: O.K. How can we prove that more rigorously? Can you explain more friendly?  Perhaps, for $f \in C^{2}_c(\mathbb{R}^n)$, over $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, the essential supremum of $|D^2f|$ and  the supremum of $|D^2f|$ are same?

Comment: I think that https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3594384/a-question-about-the-proof-of-theorem-1-section-2-2-1-of-the-evans-pde?rq=1 can be alternative for your proof..

Answer (score 1):

To answer this question, you should check which matrix norm Evan's is using. The truth of the result and proof depend on this. You can find a list of matrix norms on wikipedia.

I think that he is using the Frobenius norm, in which case the result follows because $|\Delta_{x} f(x-y)| = |TrD^{2}_{x}f(x-y)| = \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (D_{x_{i}}^{2}f(x-y))^{2}} \leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1,j=1}^{n} (D_{x_{i}}D_{x_{j}}f(x-y))^{2}} = |D^{2}_{x}f(x-y)|$

If the norm were say the spectral norm, then the result would be false because the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues and the spectral norm is only the largest eigenvalue.

Hope this helps. The norm that he is using is probably in Evan's notation appendix.